# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 298: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

I used `sed = np.loadtxt("file.dat")` to read the dat file which include different signals. However, I got `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1406: character maps to <undefined>`. May I know how can I solve this issue?
I am not sure how to read the .dat file which contains the vibration signal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix ''UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 29815: character maps to <undefined>''?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562499/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9d-in-posit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640513/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9d-in-position-x-charac

Comment: Hello @ewong, 
I also tried with ```np.loadtxt("file.dat",encoding="utf-8")``` and got the error 
```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaf in position 51: invalid start byte```
```np.loadtxt("file.dat",encoding="cp437")`` and got the error 
```ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\x00k\x00+\x00UniversalDataBinFile'```

Comment: I also tried 
``` with open("file.dat",encoding="cp437") as file:
          long_description = file.read()```
This one I don't get any issue. However, long_description is not data , It gives string which I don't need

Comment: My dat file contains
``` b>-Õ¡=\Ëˆ?)þèXÂ #†’>à …¿‚X÷>”7E?£¸Â?õÅ@?Ýö<?xKN?‚(Ï>c?ŸÛ?ÕH‹?É éXÂ Ë4¾xuŽ?Ã®‹¿Ékb¾÷¢–¿û2>o¾´Â$?¯íQ>û+Ž?\y„?™k¦?`œéXÂ 
¾[>“Ã]¿Ñ€¼½êÜ¾_/"ÀÈ{€¿bÁ|½%
2¿ˆ¾¶<"«8¿s¢ >N2ö= #éXÂ ¨ ¾#ßz?ñƒâ>]×Œ½4˜¿Ž13¿yù¿¨Á¿ú)„?ÂÓ¿i‹’¿VX¿ ©éXÂ È i<4+?$^Ô½Û‹“¿n†Š>>ŽE¿Z<ù>®{ÀñV¾ T®¿}:ä>Í7À@0éXÂ /µ= áó¾Íoé½¶#’=[M?ÿL?cû³¾#PO¿O”a>Ê¡>|í÷¾±h¿à¶éXÂ ©>”@˜$²¿ªÝþ<û…?Îú¬?2º$>š&?e4¿üOP?äI•¾ÕD=€= éXÂ Ì”ù>ƒ0¿´Ñ¾ÀCL?ÏUP?,Yœ¿LŸ¿HºŽ?TTe¿©g0?ëÒ?,”Ï? Ä
éXÂ FY¢=—³?¹²ê½ Ê›>xZ?O²F?Yš‡¿Òåº?tü=i¿@œWÅ¿$@?ÀJéXÂ LÙ½tïd¿Ä%<ê.¾>B|Ô¾â „½@åRºMÁ?‡« ¿ðú ?SH```

Comment: May I know what is this format? Actually, signal data are stored in dat file format. How can I extract this one to the data?

Comment: There is no single "dat format"; the `.dat` filename suffix is applied to files containing all sorts of different stuff. You need to find a specification of exactly what sort of data it is that you have.

Comment: It said "UDBF" file type and file extension is dat.